# Finding % of column

Tags: sql, percentage

so i have this query. With this query Im trying to get % of a single column. For example sum of all numbers in a column, then divide those numbers by a grand total number. How can i do this?

If needed more explanation, i can help explain. But please help.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Where does the "grand total" come from, if it is not the grand total?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ratio of a single row's value to the sum of the entire column, use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (col * 1.0 / sum(col) over ()) as ratio
from t;
```